# ¿Como llenar plantillas hechas en word con contenido RTF?

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, itextsharp, documentacion

Tengo en un base de datos plantillas creadas en documentos de WORD, las plantillas esta  prediseñadas con un membrete (Logo, formas, colores y diseño de la empresa) en el cuerpo de ese membrete, tengo un marcador identificado como **#Contenido**. Lo que hace mi sistema es buscar la plantilla indicada y la información que yo llene desde un textbox o que venga desde mi base de datos remplazará ese identificador llamado #Contenido.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que al momento de usar un control RichTextbox para que me guarde las características del texto como color, grosor, tamaño, estilo, viñetas, lineas etc quiero que mi plantilla se rellene respetando el formato del texto, no quiero que pierda esos estilos que vienen desde un Richtextbox o que ya esten guardado desde mi base de datos con formato RTF.

Siempre me muestrael texto de esta manera:

> {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3082{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fprq1\fcharset0 Arial Narrow;}{\f1\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}  \viewkind4\uc1\pard\li567\ri618\i\f0\fs24 Doctor\par  \b <DPR:NOMREPLEGAL>\par  \b0 Gerente\par  \pard\par  \pard\ri618\tab\par  \tab REF: Evaluaci'f3n de propuestas.\par  \pard\li567\ri618\par  \par  \pard\li567\ri-93\qj\tx9072 Mediante la presente me permito enviarle el orden  de elegibilidad, con una previa evaluaci'f3n, y teniendo en cuenta algunos aspectos tanto t'e9cnicos como econ'f3micos y comerciales, cumpliendo as'ed lo establecido en la ley 80 de 1993, en materia de contrataci'f3n.\par  \pard\li567\ri618\qj\par  \b OBJETO  DEL CONTRATO:\par  \b0 <FCTZ:OBSERVACION>\f1\fs20\par  }  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────\par PROPONENTE                           VALOR PORPUESTA   TIEMPO DE EJE.   ORDEN DE ELEC.\par ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────\par ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────\par

De esta manera es como agrego el contenido RTF que esta guardado en mi base de datos y luego lo remplazo en un documento de word:

```
Public Function ImprimirDocumento(IdBusqueda As Integer, IdPlantilla As Integer, FechaPlantilla As Date, ResponsableImpresion As String,
                                   Optional EtiquetaDocumento As String = "DOC- ")

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim AbrirPlantilla As New N_TipoPlantilla
    Dim TablaArchivo As New System.Data.DataTable
    TablaArchivo = AbrirPlantilla.DescargarArchivoPlantilla(IdPlantilla, FechaPlantilla)
    Dim Path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim Folder As String = Path & "/temp/Plantillas/"
    Dim Archivo As Byte() = TablaArchivo.Rows(0).Item("ARCHIVO")
    Dim RutaArchivo As String = Folder & TablaArchivo.Rows(0).Item("NOMBRE DOCUMENTO").ToString

    If Directory.Exists(Folder) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder)
    End If

    If Directory.Exists(RutaArchivo) = True Then
        Directory.Delete(RutaArchivo)
    End If

    File.WriteAllBytes(RutaArchivo, Archivo)

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim Neg As New Negocio.N_TipoPlantilla
    Dim Tabla As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim Etiquetas As String 'Etiquetas que seran buscadas en la plantilla para luego ser remplazadas por informacion en la base de datos
    Dim Remplazo As String  'Almacena los datos que se enviaran a la plantilla

    Tabla = Neg.CargarPlantilla(IdBusqueda, IdPlantilla)
    objWord.Visible = False
    objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=RutaArchivo, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    For Each Dc As DataColumn In Tabla.Columns
        Dim NombreColumna As String = Dc.ColumnName.ToString
        Etiquetas = "#" & NombreColumna

        For Each Dr As DataRow In Tabla.Rows
            Remplazo = Dr(NombreColumna)
            'Idvac = Dr("COD_REGISTRO")

            'BUSCAMOS EL TEXTO
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Text = Etiquetas.Trim
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = Remplazo
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=2)
        Next

    Next

    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Text = "#Usuario"
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = ResponsableImpresion
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=2)

    objWord.Activate()

    Dim FechaHoy As Date = Date.Now
    Dim F As String = CStr(Format(CDate(FechaHoy), "ddMMyyyy ( HHmmss )"))

    Dim PathApertura As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim FolderApertura As String = Path & "/temp/Documentos generados/"


    If Directory.Exists(FolderApertura) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderApertura)
    End If

    If Directory.Exists(PathApertura) = True Then
        Directory.Delete(PathApertura)
    End If

    Dim RutaDocumentoGenerado As String = FolderApertura & EtiquetaDocumento & F

    objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName:=RutaDocumentoGenerado, ExportFormat:=WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                                               OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                                               Range:=WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent,
                                               IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks,
                                               DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False)

    objWord.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    objWord.Application.Quit()


End Function
```

Agradezco me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Supongo que cargas el texto con `richTextBox1.Rtf=texto` o no?

Comment: Mi RichtextBox se carga con información en RTF y la muestra perfectamente, el problema es cuando quiero enviar ese contenido RTF a mi word, en el word no convierte el texto en formato RTF sino que lo muestra tal cual con las llaves, corchetes, slashes etc

Comment: y como lo envías  a word??? por código??

Comment: @Yussef Acabo de dejar el código que ejecuta todo el proceso de selección de plantilla y remplazo de información en el documento de Word por medio de las etiquetas.

Comment: No debes agregar información en la sección de respuestas, puedes editar tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario. Además te aconsejo reorganizar la pregunta: Tu problema es pasar de RTF a Word, que es una plantilla y que debes reemplazar es ruido innecesario, lo mismo con el código que debe ser un [MCVE], este debe ser un ejemplo, debes posibilitar que los que queremos responder copiemos y peguemos ese código sin mayor problema

Comment: Ahora sobre el fondo de la pregunta. Lo que no me queda claro es porque no guardas en RTF y ya. Word es compatible con ese formato

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera es como agrego el contenido RTF que esta guardado en mi base de datos y luego lo remplazo en un documento de word:

```
Public Function ImprimirDocumento(IdBusqueda As Integer, IdPlantilla As Integer, FechaPlantilla As Date, ResponsableImpresion As String,
                                   Optional EtiquetaDocumento As String = "DOC- ")

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim AbrirPlantilla As New N_TipoPlantilla
    Dim TablaArchivo As New System.Data.DataTable
    TablaArchivo = AbrirPlantilla.DescargarArchivoPlantilla(IdPlantilla, FechaPlantilla)
    Dim Path As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim Folder As String = Path & "/temp/Plantillas/"
    Dim Archivo As Byte() = TablaArchivo.Rows(0).Item("ARCHIVO")
    Dim RutaArchivo As String = Folder & TablaArchivo.Rows(0).Item("NOMBRE DOCUMENTO").ToString

    If Directory.Exists(Folder) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder)
    End If

    If Directory.Exists(RutaArchivo) = True Then
        Directory.Delete(RutaArchivo)
    End If

    File.WriteAllBytes(RutaArchivo, Archivo)

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Dim Neg As New Negocio.N_TipoPlantilla
    Dim Tabla As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim Etiquetas As String 'Etiquetas que seran buscadas en la plantilla para luego ser remplazadas por informacion en la base de datos
    Dim Remplazo As String  'Almacena los datos que se enviaran a la plantilla

    Tabla = Neg.CargarPlantilla(IdBusqueda, IdPlantilla)
    objWord.Visible = False
    objWord.Documents.Add(Template:=RutaArchivo, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)

    For Each Dc As DataColumn In Tabla.Columns
        Dim NombreColumna As String = Dc.ColumnName.ToString
        Etiquetas = "#" & NombreColumna

        For Each Dr As DataRow In Tabla.Rows
            Remplazo = Dr(NombreColumna)
            'Idvac = Dr("COD_REGISTRO")

            'BUSCAMOS EL TEXTO
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Text = Etiquetas.Trim
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = Remplazo
            objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=2)
        Next

    Next

    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Text = "#Usuario"
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text = ResponsableImpresion
    objWord.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace:=2)

    objWord.Activate()

    Dim FechaHoy As Date = Date.Now
    Dim F As String = CStr(Format(CDate(FechaHoy), "ddMMyyyy ( HHmmss )"))

    Dim PathApertura As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim FolderApertura As String = Path & "/temp/Documentos generados/"


    If Directory.Exists(FolderApertura) = False Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderApertura)
    End If

    If Directory.Exists(PathApertura) = True Then
        Directory.Delete(PathApertura)
    End If

    Dim RutaDocumentoGenerado As String = FolderApertura & EtiquetaDocumento & F

    objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFileName:=RutaDocumentoGenerado, ExportFormat:=WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,
                                               OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint,
                                               Range:=WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent,
                                               IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateHeadingBookmarks,
                                               DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False)

    objWord.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
    objWord.Application.Quit()


End Function
```